# Not allowed to load local resource in console for using live server at vs studio

Tags: html, ajax, visual-studio-code, npm-live-server

[image]

I've tried by changing the IP address and also changed the default browser, but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have written a nasty code which blocks some of the function of live server. Just go on element tab in dev tools and scroll down to check the script written after `<-- Code Injected by Live Server -->`.
See whether you have used the same name for any function in your any js file. If so just change their names. If this does not work then try to reinstall live server extension.

Comment: tried both but nothing works

Comment: Have you tried to change any settings of the extensions. If so, just make them default. It might resolve your problem. It can be that you might be using any code beautifier such as prettier. Check if disabling them helps you.

Comment: disabling them also not working